# Where can I find the software for "DESIGN: a program to create data entry programs" by J. Michael Wuerth?

Tags: software, c, books, database

I have a copy of the book, *DESIGN: a program to create data entry programs* by J. Michael Wuerth.

Does anyone know where I can obtain a copy of the accompanying software for the book?

Comment: Hi! Thank you for signing up for Retrocomputing Stack Exchange. We are currently in Beta right now, so every post is appreciated. However, you should ask about old computers and operating systems, as defined as [in the site tour.](https://retrocomputing.stackexchange.com/tour)

Comment: I believe that old programs (such as this) qualify for Retrocomputing; we have recently had a few about implementations of Pascal and Fortran, for example.

Comment: @Someone_who_likes_SE 27-year-old computer-related books are on-topic here ;-).

Answer (score 3):

If it is this document:

```
@book{wuerth1994design,
  title={DESIGN: A Program to Create Data Entry Programs},
  author={Wuerth, J.M. and Weise, D.R.},
  series={General technical report PSW},
  url={https://books.google.cl/books?id=h2-bP\_2P6sYC},
  year={1994},
  publisher={U.S. Department of Agriculture, Forest Service, Pacific Southwest Research Station}
}
```

it looks like a (short!) technical report. Your best bet is to rummage in any websites of the cited publisher, or the university where Google says it originated. Perhaps you can get the homepage of the author and thus get a copy of the software or more direct contact information.

In any case, 1994 is quite dated...

Comment: Well, "dated" is what we do here on RC.SE!  Look at all those 1960s' manuals that constantly turn up....

Comment: @TobySpeight I think the "In any case, 1994 is quite dated..." might have been intended to say "looks fine for this SE" as a message to Someone_who_likes_SE.

Comment: @TobySpeight, more in the sense of a question of what interest could '90ish *user interface* code have today (and the question was referred from elsewhere, so presumably not just archaeological).

Comment: @vonbrand 1994 isn't "archeological" computer history. For example GUIs had already been in use for several years. And ideas were often invented and used long before they became "mainstream". A software development project I worked in the 1970s was doing object-oriented design and programming in Fortran, but we didn't *call* it OOP (and we didn't think it was any sort of magic either - just the obvious way to deal with a very large system!) "Those who cannot remember the past are condemned to repeat it." - George Santayana, 1863–1952.

Comment: I appreciate the suggestions. I'll give some other resources a try. One person had tried to reach out to the scientist who worked on the project but wasn't able to contact him. All hope is not yet lost.